# ip works, domain doesn't, curl -v finds ip but returns empty reply

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns

My site works with ip but not with domain.

When I `curl -v 'example.com'` (with my domain in place of example) I get:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: example.com/
*   Trying 123.123.123.123...
* Connected to example.com (123.123.123.123) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

However, when I `curl -v '123.123.123.123'` (with my ip in place of 123.123.123.123) all works fine and I get:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: 123.123.123.123/
*   Trying 123.123.123.123...
* Connected to 123.123.123.123 (123.123.123.123) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 123.123.123.123
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Sun, 17 Sep 2017 06:45:56 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>Test page.</p>
    </body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 123.123.123.123 left intact
```

I get the same behavior in browsers. Hello world page shows with ip but not with domain.

**What could I possibly be missing?**

The hello world content returned when curling the ip is exactly the content of my `index.php` file as expected.

I set the DNS more than 48 hours ago so that shouldn't be the problem (and doesn't seem to be seeing curl returns the correct ip when queried on the domain).

I have tried adding a default `.htaccess` file with the content below but this didn't change the result.

```
# basic compression
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
        mod_gzip_on Yes
        mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
        mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js)$
        mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
        mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
        mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
        mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
# Protect files and directories
<FilesMatch "(\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)? |xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
        Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
# Don’t show directory listings
Options -Indexes
# Basic rewrite rules, stop unneeded PERL bot, block subversion directories
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.svn/ - [F,L]
        ErrorDocument 403 "Access Forbidden"
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
        RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have scraped stackoverflow for tonnes of similar questions but none that I've found seem to be the exact same issue.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

(PS: I'm really not sure about the tags that I've added coz I really don't know where the problem is).

Comment: Internally the "IP host" and the "domain host" might be handled by different virtual hosts inside that http server. We'd need to see the host configurations and details of the setup to be able to help.

Comment: My /etc/host.conf looks like this: 
# The "order" line is only used by old versions of the C library.
order hosts,bind
multi on

Comment: Sorry, but please don't post additional information in comments, it is impossible to read that. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_...

Comment: OK. Solved. Your tip about config sent me on the right path! I just realized that it was a server which I had set up with ServerPilot so requests via unknown domains were by default blocked. I added the domain and now it works like perfectly. Unfortunately, I thus don't know what ServerPilot has done behind the scenes. But it solves my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that. So indeed you were addressing separate virtual hosts, as I hinted to in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to let curl follow any redirect by using `-L`
So

```
curl -v -L 'example.com'
```

Comment: Wouldn't you see the redirection header in a response from the server if that were the issue?

Comment: I've just got exactly the same thing from using my own domain and it gives me exactly the results OP is having problems with.  Using -L gives the page as expected.

Comment: So this is a "empirical answer", since you did not answer my question at all ;-)

Comment: Just checked against an URL on one of my systems that performs a redirection and I clearly see the redirection header in the response. I do not see how an empty response should result in a redirection. But sure, worth a try...

Comment: In the output with a -L, I get `< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`

Comment: Hm, that does not make any sense at all any more to me, strange. The `-L` flag makes `curl` _follow_ the redirection, so you should see the resulting page or whatever object you requested. But not the redirection header. I checked and that is the behavior I see. Maybe different variants of `curl` around? But even if, that would mean that `-L` does _not_ allow you to actually access the target of the redirection.

Comment: When I try with -L i get exact same response as without.

Comment: My ip is elastic so I just tried pointing it to another server (with Rails) and there all works fine there. However, pointing it back I still have the above problem. So it must be something with the way that my php hello world server is running.

Comment: @MortenGrum Sure, I would expect no difference by the `-L` flag for an empty response...

Answer (score 0):

First thing try to check that the domain is properly configured and resolving to the IP of your instance/server:

```
dig example.com +short
```

That should give you the IP of your server in case you are not using a CDN something like [CloudFlare](http://dig%20example.com%20+short)

If that is working check that you have the web server properly configured to receive requests from your domain, in case you were using Nginx you could have something like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.example.com;
    ...
}
```

Notice the `server_name *.example.com`